API Platform - saving OneToOne ids using denormalization
I am trying to use proper normalization and denormalization for the OneToOne relation so I can persist those column's IDs without using the Processor class.
For some reason, company_id in CompanyLogo and company_logo_url_id in Company are the only ones not saved after running POST from the CompanyLogo entity?
I will post my definitions of groups and endpoints because I don't know what the issue is. Are my groups defined properly?
I would appreciate some help.
CompanyLogo entity:
#[Vich\Uploadable]
#[ORM\Entity]
#[ApiResource(
    types: ['https://schema.org/MediaObject'],
    operations: [
        new Post(
            uriTemplate: '/company/{companyId}/logo',
            inputFormats: ['multipart' => ['multipart/form-data']],
            uriVariables: [
                'companyId' => new Link(
                    fromProperty: 'companyLogoUrl',
                    fromClass: Company::class
                )
            ],
            openapi: new Model\Operation(
                requestBody: new Model\RequestBody(
                    content: new \ArrayObject([
                        'multipart/form-data' => [
                            'schema' => [
                                'type' => 'object',
                                'properties' => [
                                    'file' => [
                                        'type' => 'string',
                                        'format' => 'binary'
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ])
                )
            ),
        )
    ],
    outputFormats: ['jsonld' => ['application/ld+json']],
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['companyLogo:read']],
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['companyLogo:write']],
)]
class CompanyLogo
{
    // ... other fields

    #[ORM\OneToOne(inversedBy: 'companyLogoUrl', targetEntity: Company::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'company_id', referencedColumnName: 'id', unique: true, nullable: false)]
    #[Groups(['companyLogo:read', 'companyLogo:write'])]
    private ?Company $company = null;

Company class:
class Company
{
#[ORM\OneToOne(mappedBy: 'company', targetEntity: CompanyLogo::class, cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: true)]
    #[ApiProperty(types: ['https://schema.org/image'])]
    #[Groups(['company:read', 'company:write'])]
    public ?CompanyLogo $companyLogoUrl = null;

}

